# mobile website sliding menu is not hidden by default and is scrollable

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a mobile website:
http://mobileapi.cizgirentacar.com

Top right icon (globe) is my language menu. on Android web browsers (default one and chrome) i'm able to pull the site to left side tough i shouldn't be able to.

I don't know how to explain the problem properly. If android users can enter to site and swipe to left i think they'll understand what i mean.

What i need is to hide language menu and to make it avaliable only when guest click on globe. This have to be without breaking the sliding effect.

I hope you can help

Code:

```
 jsfiddle.net/a4amdx1y/1/
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is it just the globe or the page as a whole? Can you provide the code for said globe menu?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my first time asking a question here :)
http://jsfiddle.net/a4amdx1y/1/

Answer (score 0):

If it is sliding, then it **might be a width issue.**

Try adding this line of code into your CSS and see if it works. `html { max-width:100% }`

Comment: nope, it didn't work. i did something with "position" attribute before because of an another problem on android devices (position:fixed making page not scrollable) maybe this is where needen to check?